# Exclude all 404 errors from monolog

Tags: symfony, http-status-code-404, monolog

Currently I have monolog sending me emails when there are errors. I found that 404 errors were just polluting my email and my provider ended up suspending my account due to the number of emails I sent myself. I decided to exclude all 404 errors because all of them were due to bots looking for vulnerabilities and not from clients.

Exclude code:

`excluded_404s:
                - ^/`

The problem I'm seeing now is that symfony still logs 404 errors if the bots use http methods other than GET. My email is now polluted with entries like

`HEAD :80/phpmyAdmin/`

How can I exclude all 404 errors including those using http methods other than GET?

*Edit:*
Oh boy. Beginner mistake here. It seems that after my last deploy of the configuration I did not clear the prod cache and I'm figuring out that the config is cached. I'm using deployer to deploy my code updates but I guess the clear cache command is missing from it.

Comment: are you doing this http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html ?

Comment: Updated my question to include the setting to exclude 404s. All GET 404s are excluded as expected. The other http methods still get logged though.

Comment: not sure if its a bug, will try to reproduce it.. any chance that you can just use a different logging level , ie use error instead of debug.

Comment: Great thanks. I'm using symfony 2.8. I'm thinking I may need to manually handle those errors with kernel exception listener

Comment: Well I'm embarrassed to say that I'm wrong here. Seems I'm getting emails for all 404s from production but in dev the Config works. More testing I guess.

Comment: Is it possible you put the changes in `config_dev.yml`?

Comment: No the monolog entries are the same for prod and dev. I literally cleared the prod cache tested and no email was generated. Pretty sure I read somewhere that Config is cached but maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 4):

Symfony 4.1.  can be configured to ignore HTTP Codes but only the fingers_crossed handler:

## config/packages/monolog.yaml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            # ...
            type: 'fingers_crossed'
            excluded_http_codes: [404]
```

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-ignore-specific-http-codes-from-logs

Answer (score 2):

In Symfony 4/5 you can do:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getThrowable();
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            $response = new Response($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getStatusCode());
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

and

```
App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but it is the 1st one when googling.
Meanwhile I found a solution for symfony 3.4, if you need to exclude all 404 errors from your logs you can create an ExceptionListener and check if the exception is a NotFoundHttpException.
If it is the case, then just return a response so that the event is stopped and the logger will not handle the exception.

src/AppBundle/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if (! $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            return;
        }
        $response = new Response($exception->getMessage(), $exception->getStatusCode());
        // returning a response stop the event propagation
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
  app.exception.listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```