# How not to display 404 errors in symfony logs (monolog) in a dev environment?

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I would like to make a configuration for my symfony logs in dev environment that allows to log all messages except 404 errors.

I tested the following configuration:

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler: nested
        excluded_http_codes: [404]
        buffer_size: 50


    nested:
        type: rotating_file
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: ["!event"]
        max_files: 30
```

With this configuration, 404 messages don't appear in the logs but the problem is that messages like "event.DEBUG" or "request.INFO" don't appear either and I would like them to appear because I am in a dev environment.

So I thought that the "action_level" was too high so I modified it:

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type: fingers_crossed
        action_level: debug   <========== I replaced error with debug
        handler: nested
        excluded_http_codes: [404]
        buffer_size: 50

    nested:
        type: rotating_file
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: ["!event"]
        max_files: 30
```

Now in the logs, I can see "event.DEBUG" or "request.INFO" messages but I also see 404 errors...

It's like the excluded_http_codes is not working.

My question is how can I do to not show 404 errors in the logs while keeping messages like "event.DEBUG" or "request.INFO"?

Thank you (and apologies for my English)

Comment: What version of Symfony & MonologBundle/Bridge are you using? I think you may need to use `excluded_404s: [^/]` instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude all 404 errors from monolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327523/exclude-all-404-errors-from-monolog)

Comment: excluded_404s doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What of my first sentence, any idea what versions of Symfony, MonologBundle and MonologBridge you are using? It's important because Certain features were not available in earlier versions and others were removed in later versions. To best help resolve the problem, we'd need to know the feature-set being utilized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ErrorListener which is responsible for HTTP error logging and overrides the default ErrorListener. In the code below, the dev environment is determined by `$this->debug` property which contains `APP_DEBUG` env variable.

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener as BaseErrorListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;

class ErrorListener extends BaseErrorListener
{
    protected function logException(\Throwable $exception, string $message, string $logLevel = null): void
    {
        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            if (null !== $logLevel) {
                $this->logger->log($logLevel, $message, ['exception' => $exception]);
            } elseif (!$exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface || $exception->getStatusCode() >= 500) {
                $this->logger->critical($message, ['exception' => $exception]);
            } else {
                // beginning of changes
                if ($exception->getStatusCode() !== 404 || !$this->debug) {
                    $this->logger->error($message, ['exception' => $exception]);
                }
                // ending of changes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And register this listener

```
namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\EventListener\ErrorListener;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class ErrorListenerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        // override `exception_listener`
        $exceptionListenerDefinition = $container->getDefinition('exception_listener');
        $exceptionListenerDefinition->setClass(ErrorListener::class);
    }
}
```